# How do I access an individual 'type' inside std::list< std::list< type > >

Tags: c++, list, struct, iterator, std

I am creating a function that recursively finds structs within structs.
I create a `list < list <struct> >` and then I call a function that finds the first `list <struct>` and pushes it to the back of a list. I need to iterate through that list of structs and look for more structs within.

Here is my code, this may make things more clear.

```
std::list<std::list<iof_chunk>>     read_ALLChunks  (iof_chunk* reading_material)
{
    std::list< std::list<iof_chunk> > ALL_CHUNKS;
    std::list< std::list<iof_chunk> >::iterator iter;

    if ( ((*reading_material).header.BASEID_Code != 'BODY') && (checkfor_header( &(*reading_material).data[20] )) )
    {
        ALL_CHUNKS.push_back( read_subChunks(reading_material) );
        for( int i = 0; i < ALL_CHUNKS.size; ++i)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**My Question about the code above:** How do I access an `iof_chunk` in `ALL_CHUNKS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather easy way to do this is with the `auto` keyword, like so..

```
auto iter = myList.begin();
```

This is equivalent to..

```
std::list< std::list<T> >::iterator iter = myList.begin();
```

The thing to remember is that every level of list you add will add a corresponding iterator between you and the type `T`

So for example, if we have two lists ie. `std::list<std::list<T>>` we'll need to use two iterators to get to any `T` values.

```
std::list<std::list<T>> myList;
auto iter1 = myList.begin();
auto iter2 = iter1->begin();
T value = *iter2; //assuming iter2 != iter1->end()
```

So for a moderately more complex example, with a more useful bit of code supporting it, take the following..

```
//list x 4
std::list< std::list< std::list< std::list<T> > > > myCrazyList;
for(auto iter1 = myCrazyList.begin(); iter1 != myCrazyList.end(); ++iter1){
    for(auto iter2 = iter1->begin(); iter2 != iter1->end(); ++iter2){
        for(auto iter3 = iter2->begin(); iter3 != iter2->end(); ++iter3){
            for(auto iter4 = iter3->begin(); iter4 != iter3->end(); ++iter4){
                T& value = *iter4;
                //do stuff to your T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see `auto` can be instrumental in keeping sane when dealing with long types like this. `iter4` would be equivalent to `std::list<T>::iterator` but `iter1` on the other hand has all 4 `std::list` in the type-name.

In fact, there is an even easier way to do this:

```
for(auto level_0 : myCrazyList)
   for(auto level_1 : level_0)
      for(auto level_2 : level_1)
         for(auto &myT : level_2)
            //do stuff to your T value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterator in this way:

```
std::list< std::list<iof_chunk> > ALL_CHUNKS;
std::list< std::list<iof_chunk> >::iterator i = ALL_CHUNKS.begin();
std::list<iof_chunk> one_chunk;

for(; i != ALL_CHUNKS.end(); ++i) {
  *i = one_chunk;
  /* it's just an example */
}
```

**edit**

```
std::list< std::list<iof_chunk> > ALL_CHUNKS;
std::list< std::list<iof_chunk> >::iterator i = ALL_CHUNKS.begin();


for(; i != ALL_CHUNKS.end(); ++i) {
  std::list<iof_chunk> i-th_chunkList = *i;
  std::list<iof_chunk>::iterator j = *i.begin();
  for(; j != *i.end(); ++j) {
    /* do your operation with *j that is an iof_chunk object */
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `*i = one_chunk` doing? Also why does the for loop iterate increment i if we change its value inside?

Comment: *i=one_chunk it's only an example to explain how you can access the object "pointed" by the iterator. "i" is the iterator, "*i" is the object pointer by the iterator. In this case, "i" is an iterator on object of list<iof_chunk>, so "*i" will be the a single list of iof_chunk. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this statement is invalid because there is no identifier that is being declared.

```
std::list< std::list<iof_chunk> >::iterator;
```

As for your question then you can use the following construction

```
for ( iof_chunk &chunk : ALL_CHUNKS.back() )
{
   // do something
}
```